# spoofed emails from my domain to me

Tags: spoofing

Not sure if this is the right place but I'm at a loss!

Someone has setup a network monitor using "PRTG Network Monitor" from a company called Paessler AG and they've directed that reports from this utility be sent to "jmanderville@mydomain.com".

I'm getting hundreds of emails a day from this automated network monitoring software and the emails are coming from my own domain "mydomain.com" from the same person they're being sent to "jmanderville@mydomain.com"

I've spoken with the people at the company that sells the software, Paessler AG, and they say there's nothing they can do. I don't want to mark the emails as spam, junk, or block them as I don't want my domain to be blacklisted.

While it seems someone must be doing this on purpose it makes little sense that they've purchased software just to be annoying? And, if they simply made a mistake in configuring the software wouldn't they notice they're not getting reports?

This has been going on for 6 months and it's driving me crazy!

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Rob

Header information:

```
Return-Path: <jmanderville@MYDOMAIN.com>
Received: from [74.208.5.3] ([74.208.5.3]) by mx.perfora.net (mxeueus005
 [74.208.5.3]) with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 1MAwwX-1hdZd22OzJ-00BJAA for
 <robertg@MYDOMAIN.com>; Mon, 08 Jul 2019 10:36:02 +0200
Received: from ASBASBS ([184.188.212.139]) by mx.perfora.net (mxeueus005
 [74.208.5.3]) with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 1Mlvep-1iA9YY2M1T-00j0Lo for
 <jmanderville@MYDOMAIN.com>; Mon, 08 Jul 2019 10:36:01 +0200
X-Mailer: PRTG Network Monitor 19.1.48.2929
From: "PRTG Network Monitor" <jmanderville@MYDOMAIN.com>
Subject: [PRTG Network Monitor (ASBASBS)] XC-641364 Disk Free: Hard Disk
 (Partition P) (SNMP Disk Free) Down ended (now: Unknown)  (No data since
 7/8/2019 1:32:45 AM)
To: jmanderville@MYDOMAIN.com
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="multipart/alternative"; boundary="NqYM1nHTyfQ3wYh4FsiRpNPUZdBRmho=_V"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 8 Jul 2019 01:36:01 -0700
Priority: urgent
X-Priority: 1
Envelope-To: <robertg@MYDOMAIN.com>
X-Spam-Flag: NO
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [message header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_header)s! These will tell you where the email came from (the "From" field means nothing, really). Please edit your question to include the headers (suitably anonymized). Then maybe we can help...

Comment: What do you use for hosting your domain's mail? Custom server or commercial hosted service?

Comment: The headers - I edited and included in the oroginal post - don't seem to help much, that I can see, other than they come from a Rackspace.com server.

Comment: I use 1and1 for email.

Comment: Do you have SPF or DKIM records set up on your domain?

Comment: I don't - I was just now looking into setting those up. Will those prevent this without harming my domain reputation? Also - I was wondering - is there a way to block/redirect (I'd lvoe to redirect these back to the company - I'm sure they'd find out who was doing it at that point...lol) emails based on subject line that doesn't harm the domain rep?

Comment: Is your ISP called Cox Communications Inc? If not, then that's the originating company (and I can explain why).

Comment: No, not Cox...I use 1and1 (Ionos is their new name).

Answer (score 0):

(Setting the email `from` address to be the same as `to` is one of the most
frustrating tricks in marketing.)

Analyzing the headers:

The Subject line is "PRTG Network Monitor (ASBASBS)", so the computer being
monitored seems to be named `ASBASBS`.
In the `Received` header we can see that its IP address is `184.188.212.139`.

Querying [whois.arin.net](http://whois.arin.net/ui/) for this IP address
gives as
[answer](https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-184-188-208-0-1/pft?s=184.188.212.139)
the company `Cox Communications Inc`.

You may find here the email address `abuse@cox.net` which you may try to contact,
since what you are experiencing is certainly an abuse.

If you get no answer, you may try the other listed emails:
`sophea.long@cox.com`, `mark.goodwin@cox.com`, `cari.merola@cox.com`,
`tori.berube@cox.com` and `alvin.anderson@cox.com`,
in the hope that one of them is still answering.
You can also find phone numbers for each one, which you may also try.
They are all situated in Atlanta.

Comment: Thank you - I completely missed that IP address! What is that "19.1.48.2929"? I appreciate all your help everyone...FYI - need to head for a while so I'm not ignoring :)

Comment: `19.1.48.2929` is the PRTG Network Monitor software version. In the [Release Notes for the "Stable" Release Channel](https://www.paessler.com/prtg/history/stable) it dates from March 4th 2019.

Comment: BTW, you may also perhaps be able of setting up a spam rule based on the Subject header, if your email software supports that.

Comment: Interesting - this started a month after that release. I'll research the subject header/spam rule ability. Thank you all!